# I can't get my image to fill the area of my grid

Tags: javascript, css

I have a 300x300 image that I'd like to fit into a grid (sized 158x175), but when I have...

```
<div className='box'>
   <div className='test'>
      <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/300x300' alt='Image Example'/>
   </div>
   <div className='test'>
      <p>Random text</p>
   </div>
   <div className='test'>
      <p>Random text</>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
box {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 158px auto auto;
   grid-template-rows: 175px;

   div.test {
      &:first-child {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         object-fit: cover;
      }
   }
}
```

like I've seen a lot of people say from doing some research, the 300x300 block shrinks to 158x158, leaving about 17px of grid space left below the image. I would like the image to be cropped to fit the entire space, but I can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I have also tried replacing `height: 100%;` to `height: auto`, and that moves my image down a few pixels, but I pretty much have the same issue as before.

Answer (score 0):

couple of things!

1. make sure that 'box' in your css is '.box'
2. &:first-child

locks on to the occurrence of div.test, not div.test's first child.

So if you simply change your scss to be:

```
.box {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 158px auto auto;
   grid-template-rows: 175px;

   div.test {
      img {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         object-fit: cover;
      }
   }
}
```

Here is a codepen for you:
https://codepen.io/webdevjones/pen/LYQPZaM

Comment: Yeah I just forgot to put the dot there because I'm changing some of the class names and such for this post. I'm not sure why, but that still doesn't work for me. I changed the `&:first-child` to `img`, and my image didn't move at all